# Google blocks automated requests after 60 to 70 successful requests

Tags: c#

I am developing in window service where I try fetch the page rank from  `http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?q=info:(domainName)`.

The problem is when I run the thread then after 60 to 70 request google block our requests and the following error is returned:

> The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

How do I solve that?

Comment: I'd edit that question to be more pertinent to your problem.  You need not post your alleged qualifications.

Comment: And I tried to make the question more specific.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you could try, to avoid googles bot detection, which blocks you:

- Sleep in between the requests for at least a second.
- Vary your user agent string (just a guess)
- Vary your IP address (-> use proxy servers to route your requests)

Comment: 503 is a server error, not a client error.  Maybe Google's error code is intentionally misleading, but I'd expect a 4xx code if you're making too many requests.

Comment: http://techydave.blogspot.com/2010/04/googles-automated-search-query-capture.html It's intentionally misleading

Comment: i have checked after 20 second sleep after one request then also block my request actually i need vary quikly checking becuase i have more then 5000000 records,

thanks for solution but please make sur my requriments

Comment: Google blocks automated queries. No way around it but wait some time after each and every request. Even than it isn't guaranteed, that Google won't detect you are a bot. Google really doesn't care about your requirements...